# Javascript: Associative Array to Return Information Relating to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have an array of students names and the grades they earned for the semester. How could I get my javascript code to return the first names of all the students that earned an "A" grade based off of my array? I know this is way off but this is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Javascript</title>
    <script>
    var grades= [];

    grades [0] = "F";
    student [0] = "John";
    grades [1] = "D";
    student [1] = "George";
    grades [2] = "C";
    student [2] = "Bill";
    grades [3] = "B";
    student [3] = "Ted";
    grades [4] = "A";
    student [4] = "Rick";

    function getNames ()
    {

        for (var i =0;i <grades.length;i++)
            {
        if (grades[1] = "F")
            {
            document.getElementById("lowgrade").innerHTML= student[1];
            }
        else if(grades[1] = "D")
            {
            document.getElementById("midlowgrade").innerHTML= student[1];
            }
        else if(grades[1] = "C")
            {
            document.getElementById("midgrade").innerHTML= student[1];
            }
        else if(grades[1] = "B")
            {
            document.getElementById("highgrade").innerHTML= student[1];
            }
        else if(grades[1] = "A")
            {
            document.getElementById("bestgrade").innerHTML = student[1];
            }

    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
    <form name = "f1">
    Enter Grade<input type ="text" id="grades" name="wed" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Check Student" onclick="getNames()" />
    </form>
    <div id="text" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so many problems,   you are using =  instead of == or ===..... you have grads[1] instead of grades[i].   You need to do some basic debugging of your own homework before asking here.

Comment: You're assigning values in each of your `if`s.  Check out [comparisons](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStudentsByGrade(grade){
var grade_students = [];

for(var i=0;i < students.length;i++){
if(grades[i] == grade){
grade_students.push(students[i]);
}
}
return grade_students;
}

var grade_a_students = getStudentsByGrade("A");
```

Comment: You guys are all amazing, thank you so much. I'm extremely new to this whole thing and that was a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNames(){
  for(var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
    if(grades[i] == "F"){
      document.getElementById("lowgrade").innerHTML = student[i];
    }
    else if(grades[i] == "D"){
      document.getElementById("midlowgrade").innerHTML = student[i];
    }
    else if(grades[i] == "C"){
      document.getElementById("midgrade").innerHTML = student[i];
    }
    else if(grades[i] == "B"){
      document.getElementById("highgrade").innerHTML = student[i];
    }
    else if(grades[i] == "A"){
      document.getElementById("bestgrade").innerHTML = student[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Some mistakes you made:

1. You used 1 instead of i.
2. You used = instead of ==.
3. You forgot to close the for with }.
4. You got the identation wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = [
  {name: "John", grade: "F"},
  {name: "George", grade: "D"}
] //obviously fill the rest

function getByGrade(grade){
  return students.filter(function(student){
    return student.grade.toUpperCase() == grade.toUpperCase();
  });
});

As = getByGrade('F');
Bs = getByGrade('D');
```

(and so on)

or perhaps something like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'].map(function(letter){
  return students.filter(function(student){
     return student.grade.toUpperCase() == letter; //if all the letters are uppercased already on the student objects then no need for `toUpperCase()`
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I then let the user input the grade and return the students? I mean how do I allow for an input and then assign this function to a button which will get the name of the person associated with this grade? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I'm assuming you're a beginner in javascript so go on to http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ltDSRMVlrJ and I'll help you out.

Comment: I was waiting now if you want

Comment: I saved your email delete that comment so you don't get spammed by people who see this question.